# Rendering obstacles with stage object

Tags: android, libgdx, rendering

Okay here's my question. I am trying to create a platformer game. My character is able to translate; as well as, the orthographic camera I created.
I am trying to add a button with click capabilities to serve as a virtual controller. I am using a Stage class object to render it. The button renders but not to an appropriate size. Also, when it renders my character does not render at all. I am sorry I did not post any code for my problem, but could someone give me an idea of how to do this. It seems like I have to make my class implement the Screen interface, or can I do this another way? I do create a fitViewport that has my orthographic camera and assign this fitviewport to my stage. I believe this is where the problem might be. Perhaps in my resize method I am not resizing it well. Please give me some ideas as to how can I render this button with the stage class that will use my orthographic camera, which I will be able to control as I wish. Also, remember I am not implementing the screen interface that seems to be a requirement of any class that creates stage objects.

thanks for any ideas

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using two cameras for each of the task. One for rendering your game entities like character, platform that could use virtual pixel size(say 15x20) for SpriteBatch.

And the other camera can be used to draw screen ui like buttons(jump/move). Second camera will be set to exact pixel coordinates and will be used with Stage.